# Is there any function are available to get most accurate location using fusedlocation provider client in android

Tags: android

I am getting location through Fused location provider client. But not getting accurate location . Can you suggest me how i can get 100% accurate location in android.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can suggest [this](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current#BestEstimate).